# Label inside TableViewCell is not scaling horizontally

Tags: ios, uitableview

I add a UITableViewController to my storyboard. This TVC controller is adjusted to freeform and its width is 320.

I add a label centered in X, inside the prototype cell. I anchor that label using autolayout as follows:

1. leading to superview = 10
2. trailing to superview = 10
3. center Y to superview
4. height = 20

I open the preview tab on xcode, so I am seeing the label centered on the cell.

Now I select the tableViewController and change its size to 400.

The label is not centered on the cell anymore. Wasn't it supposed to be?

Comment: Label text has a property textAlignment.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to horizontally and vertically center align a label in its container if you want it centered in a prototype cell. I would get rid of your constraints, select the label, and then select Editor > Align > "Horizontal center in container" and then Editor > Align > "Vertical center in container."

Note that if you do it this way, after you select the label and then choose "Horizontal center in container" from the Align menu, the label will no longer be selected so you'll have to select the label again before choosing "Vertical center in container" from the Align menu.

The leading space is what's screwing up your centering, I believe.

Comment: XCode is not liking that.

Comment: @UFO I do it like this all the time and it's worked every time. Two constraints--one horizontal center and one vertical center. Make sure you get rid of all the other constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to call invalidateIntrinsicContentSize for cell that changed size. Layout engine needs to know that something has changed.